# References request on characteristic class

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am planing to learn something about characteristic classes on my own. I am wondering if anyone could recommend me something on such materials like constructions of vector bundles, Thom isomorphism theorem with applications and intersection theory. I have a foundation on differential manifolds, riemannian geometry and elmentary algebraic topology, i.e (co)homology groups, kunneth formular, Poincare dualities and so on.

Because I don't have too much time on it, I hope the references could be very readable, concise and ideal for self-studying.

I will appreciate if any one may recommend such references. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if you are still looking into this, but....  I have LaTeXed Milnor's mimeographed notes "Lectures on characteristic classes".  It is the precursor of the one mentioned by "anomaly" below.  I guess the original notes have still some value, seeing that late Andrew Ranicki has listed them in his online "Library". If you are interested to have a copy, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical reference is Milnor and Stasheff's "Characteristic Classes." It's definitely readable, concise, and amenable to self-study; my only (very minor) complaint about it is that it's a bit reluctant to stay within the paracompact or CW-complex category. I also like Husemoller's "Fiber Bundles," which covers a bit of topological K-theory as well. If you have a basic background in algebraic topology, you shouldn't have a problem with either book.

Comment: Hatcher's notes are also nice, even if they don't go into as many topics as M-S. For the more algebraically minded, Bruner-Catanzaro-May have an in-progress book floating around the internet, too.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, anomaly. Also thank @MikeMiller for your useful comments.

Comment: @MikeMiller Do you have a link for that in-progress book?

Comment: @SeanTilson I think I was referring to [this](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CHAR/charclasses.pdf).

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you very much!